# Error when installing windows SDK 7.1

Tags: windows, sdk, visual-c++-2010

I've run into an error when installing the Windows SDK that I've seen posted around the Internet, but none of the solutions are working for me. Here is the log I'm getting

```
9:43:37 AM Monday, October 14, 2013: SFX C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\SFX\vcredist_x64.exe installation started with log file C:\Users\clarkbd\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7_c3c42538-8a3e-439d-be39-aee3078ca098_SFX.log
9:43:43 AM Monday, October 14, 2013: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\SFX\vcredist_x64.exe installation failed with return code 1603
9:43:53 AM Monday, October 14, 2013: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Installation of Product Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (failed): Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information. Stack:    at SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureRelatedSfx()    at SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct(ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)
9:43:53 AM Monday, October 14, 2013: [SDKSetup:Info] Config_Products_InstallNew: End installation of new product: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7
9:43:53 AM Monday, October 14, 2013: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Windows SDK Setup (failed): Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information. Stack:    at SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct(ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)      at SDKSetup.Product.SetupProduct(TaskMode taskMode, ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)       at SDKSetup.ProductCollection.SetupProducts(TaskMode taskMode, DownloadManager downloadManager, ManualResetEvent cancelEvent)       at SDKSetup.ConfigProducts.DoCurrentTask(TaskMode Task)
```

When I try to run vcredist_x64 separately, I get this error:

```
MSI (s) (80:5C) [09:51:50:971]: Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.30319 -- A later version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.30319 is already installed.
```

Now, as per every solution I've read about this online, I'd uninstall the redistributable and continue with the installation. The problem is that I don't have any VC++ 2010 redistributables installed (only 2005 and 2008). The only thing besides the main program is something called `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express Prerequisites x64 - ENU`. Uninstalling this has no effect on the errors I receive. There's something on my computer that's telling the SDK I have this redist installed, but I'm not sure what. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Edit: This problem persists even when I completely uninstall Visual C++ 2010. What else can I do to remove all traces of this software from my machine?

Edit 2: After searching the registry a bit, I've found that NI installs its own visual c++ 2010 redistributable with one of its programs, but it isn't included in the "Add or Remove Programs" list. I've uninstalled this and hopefully the sdk will install properly.

Edit 3: No luck, still getting the same error. I can find other 2010 redistributables in the registry, but trying to execute the uninstall string manually just tells me that I can only run it on installed packages. This would be much simpler if I knew how the vcredist finds currently installed redistributions.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Success! I was able to purge the vc++ 2010 redistributables from my machine using Microsoft's Fix it utility: http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall

It was able to find both the x64 and x86 versions of the redistributable and uninstall it, removing ~120 entries from the registry and allowing the sdk installation to go forward. It had nothing to do with NI's version of the vc++ 2010 redistributable.

Comment: This answer helped me, but for me using "Add or Remove Programs" was enough.

Comment: It is for most people. Not in my case, though =/

Comment: My error in the log was `DDSet_Error: Patch Hooks: Missing required property 'ProductFamily': Setup cannot continue.` and  `DDSet_Error: Patch Hooks: Missing required property 'ProductFamily': Setup cannot continue.
DDSet_Warning: Setup failed while calling 'getDLLName'. System error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`  Uninstalling the C++ 2010 redists for x86 and x64 solved this for me.

Comment: Altough I removed all VC++ redistributables from my machine using "Add or Remove Programs" that wasn't enough. But after using Microsoft's Fix It Utility, mentioned by @RedAlert, the SDK installation worked for me.

Comment: I tried the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901279/windows-7-sdk-installation-failure
which got me further, but got stuck on a improperly uninstalled VC++ Compiler.
So while it wasn't the redistributables for me, I managed to use Fix it to uninstall the stuff that blocked my install.
Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution helped, the question is: why does Microsoft not fix this issue? I mean, this is only a workaround by replacing the VC2010 redist with an older one :(

Comment: I used the troubleshooter and said I had a problem uninstalling something. From the list I chose to uninstall "Windows SDK Intellidocs". After this I was able to install the SDK.

Answer (score 134):

This is a known issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426

**CAUSE**

> This issue occurs when you install the Windows 7 SDK on a computer
>   that has a newer version of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable
>   installed.

**RESOLUTION**

> To resolve this issue, you must uninstall all versions of the Visual
>   C++ 2010 Redistributable before installing the Windows 7 SDK.  You may
>   have one or more of the following products installed:
>
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable
>
> After uninstalling the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
>   Redistributable products, you may install the Windows 7 SDK.  After
>   installing the Windows 7 SDK, you may then reinstall the newer version
>   of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable products, in order to restore
>   the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable products to their original state.

[image: uninstallation picture]

Comment: I had two of these. Removing them made the SDK install.

Comment: The latest version (as of now) is called `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package` and is version `10.0.40219.1`. Too k me a while to figure out I needed to search for `SP1`, so leaving this here for others.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with Windows SDK web installer on Win7 Prof 64bit. Uninstalling/reinstalling VS 2010 redistributables didn't help. Only after downloading Windows SDK ISO file the installation completed successfully (the one for x64 is GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso).

My theory would be that web installer chose wrong architecture somehow causing installation to fail.

Answer (score 2):

All of the above answers helped me but none really worked for me.

I finally managed to compile 64 bits with Visual Express 2010 by installing the SDK **before** Visual Express 2010.
So:

1. (uninstall Visual Express 2010, maybe using [this registry hack](https://superuser.com/questions/325963/error-in-installing-windows-sdk-newer-version-already-installed) if some Visual Compilers are still seen as installed but not shown in the "Programs and Features" panel)
2. Install Windows SDK
3. Install Visual Express 2010
4. [Configure the default library search path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9836162/1098603) to point at the SDK

I'm lazy to uninstall Visual Express, reinstall the SDK and then again Visual Express, but I got it all in a VirtualBox VM which I will preciously keep in a safe at the bank! ;)