# Using Visual Studio 2013's C compiler for MATLAB

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, visual-studio-2013, simulink

I added Visual Studio 2013 as the default C compiler for MATLAB using the `mex -setup` command. I added Visual Studio 2013 using a download I found on the internet with the following instructions.

```
The files 
  * msvc120engmatopts.bat
  * msvc120opts.bat
  * msvc120opts.stp
should be copied to C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mexopts .

The files 
  * msvc120compp.bat
  * msvc120compp.stp
should be copied to C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64\mbuildopts .
```

My version of MATLAB is R2011b, so I replaced the path appropriately.

Here's me using it to run a C function to verify if the compiler has been linked.

[**Log File**](http://pastebin.com/0gYNYrbx)

I found out about this method from this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12450944/1154689).

However, when I use a MATLAB function within a Simulink Model, I get the following error message just like I did before I linked the VS2013 compiler to MATLAB.

```
Unable to locate a C-compiler required by Stateflow and MATLAB Function blocks.
Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported C-compiler.
```

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit matlab?

Comment: @patrik - Yes I'm running 64 bit Matlab. I even used MinGW-64.

Comment: I am not sure here, but you may need a 64-bit compiler.

Comment: @patrik - Both VS2013 and minGW-64 are 64 bit compilers.

Comment: Are you sure that VS2013 is a 64-bit compiler? I have not used VS2013, but from the experience of earlier versions, the default compiler have been a 32-bit compiler. However, minGW-64 should work then. I have no clue.

Comment: @patrik - No sure about VS2013 because there are no VS 64 bit editions, so I doubt the compiler will be 64-bit. But yes, minGW-64 should work. It works fine on Matlab, just not on Simulink.

Comment: Yes, Visual C++ includes a 64-bit compiler.  And a 32-bit compiler.  The same 32-bit IDE interfaces to compilers of all architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the only thing that works for my version of [**MATLAB "R2011b"**](http://www.mathworks.in/support/compilers/R2011b/win32.html) is Microsoft SDK 7.1 since the other compilers are too old for Windows 7 64 bit. MinGW-64 bit is unsupported. Although it works on MATLAB it is not recognized by Stateflow.

So I just downloaded the .iso file from [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True).

If you face any difficulty while installing the SDK, then try [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23032807/1154689).

Comment: Other compilers are too old?  Visual Studio 2013 is newer than either MATLAB 2011b or Windows 7.