# How the lower version MATLAB to use high edition visual studio C compiler [For example: Matlab 2012b use visual studio 2013 compiler ]

Tags: matlab, visual-studio

i try to use SPArse Modeling Software [ Version: 2.5,matlab interface ], it need to compiler first.so i run the compiler.m in  MATLAB 2012b .but it goes wrong.

Here is the log

---

```
>> compile
Warning: Directory already exists. 

> In compile at 144 

compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./decomp/ -I./prox/ -I./dictLearn/ dictLearn/mex/mexArchetypalAnalysis.cpp

  Error: Could not find the compiler "g++-4" on the DOS path. 
         Use mex -setup to configure your environment properly. 


  D:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unable to locate compiler. 


Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in compile (line 440)
    mex(args{:});
```

---

I guess the problem is the MATLAB 2012b  mismatching the compiler in PC.

And I try to use visual studio 2013 as my the default C compiler for MATLAB 2012b.
when i using the mex -setup command.
only two choice as follow ,and do not see the visual studio 2013 compiler.

Select a compiler:

[1] Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0

[0] None

I know MATLAB 2014b can use visual studio 2013 C compiler.

**But how the lower version MATLAB to use high edition  visual studio C compiler.**

Someone else encountered this problem ?

My OS is windows 7 X64  , visual studio 2013 PRO,  MATLAB 2012b.

I reference this ,but seems did't work.

[Using Visual Studio 2013's C compiler for MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868529/using-visual-studio-2013s-c-compiler-for-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler you are trying to use [is not supported by your matlab version](http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2012b_SupportedCompliers.pdf), you have to use one of the supported compilers.