# Error installing superset on an anaconda distribution

Tags: python, conda, python-3.4, apache-superset

Having a nightmare here, been trying for hours with no luck. I'm using anaconda with a virtual environment on python 3.4 (I want to use geopandas, can't use 3.5) on windows 10. This is superset by the way: https://github.com/airbnb/superset

I also tried in my root conda environment but same issues.

First I do

```
activate py34
```

Then I tried two methods, A)

```
pip install superset
```

gives the error message

> error: Microsoft visual c++ 10.0 is required. get it with "microsoft windows sdk 7.1" python

and B)
Download the source files and go to the directory and

```
setup.py install
```

Produces a different output but the same error message.

So I tried installing the SDK as suggested (standard UI installation like a normal windows program), but then I get an error with no code or information provided:

> Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information"

There is no error code provided and I also don't know where that ConfigDetails.htm file is.

I tried installing a more recent SDK found here but still the same problems: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Any ideas? I'm relatively new to python and find packages the most difficult thing ever, so if the answer is obvious then sorry.

Comment: The second issue occurs when you install the Windows 7 SDK on a computer that has a newer version of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable installed.

Comment: Thy [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366006/error-when-installing-windows-sdk-7-1) solution, and repeat the steps.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Migrating OP's solution from a comment to an answer:</sup>

> In the end the best solution was to install Cygwin and install Superset within Linux.

- [AndyMoore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4804026/andymoore) - [Mar 2, 2017 at 20:50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533906/error-installing-superset-on-an-anaconda-distribution#comment72265286_42533906)