# node-gyp: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, node.js, node-gyp

Enviromnent is :

> Window server 2008 R2 Standard Service Pack1 Build 7601 (64bits) Node
>   js: v.0.10.25 (64 bits) npm: 1.3.24

I am using Visual Studio 2010  Express.
I have been trying to build a module for days now ...
Followed the wiki on https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Visual-Studio-2010-Setup

I have also have tried  the [visual studio 2010 express + win sdk = cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821700/visual-studio-2010-express-win-sdk-cannot-open-input-file-kernel32-lib). I can produce a module, but then when I try to use it I get
node server.js
   module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I am using node v0.10.25 (64bit version)

Any help really welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up and used Visual Studio 2012. Everything is ok now.

Comment: I have installed both VS 2010 and VS2012, do yo uninstalled you VS2010? and do you installed other dependency? Thanks

Comment: Just removed VS2010, no other dependency, as I recall